# how can i get the value of an azure cli list command into a variable?

Tags: azure, powershell

When i run the following command in azure, I want to place the value of the "name" in a variable like $ipconfigname. The output lists out many other values but I only need this one value "name" in the variable, how can i accomplish this?

az network nic ip-config list -g rg01 --nic-name vmnic01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when you use the `list` command, it means the output must be a list no matter how many members it has. So as you want, the variable `$ipconfigname` actually is a list of the config name. You can use the Azure CLI command to set the variable like below only with the name list:

```
$ipconfigNames = az network nic ip-config list -g rg01 --nic-name vmnic01 --query "[].name" -o tsv
```

Answer (score 4):

The az cli outputs JSON so if you run your command from a PowerShell prompt you can use ConvertFrom-Json to create an object from the output and then get the property you need

```
$IpConfig = az network nic ip-config list -g rg01 --nic-name vmnic01 | ConvertFrom-Json
$IpConfigName = $IpConfig.name
```